# json accumulate(String,String) method not found

Tags: java, netbeans, json, accumulate

I am trying to use JSONObject in my Servlet class using Netbeans , I imported several versions of json simple jar , but accumulate method is not there ,infact none of the json methods are there when i try to use autocomplete for methods on json object.
Any Reasons ?

Comment: what makes you think it should be there?

Comment: sorry ? isnt it in the json library ?

Comment: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html the very first method

Comment: that's the doc for that library: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java (there are plenty others)

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but, what makes you think there is such a method? As you can see on the screenshot, neither JSONObject nor any other class of this library have this method.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQieo.png)

Following the Javadoc link you've provided it appears that you're using **json-simple** library but following Javadoc for **org.json** library.

I haven't found ready-to-use jar-file for this library so I builded it by myself from GitHub sources. [Here is the link on Google Drive.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1fw86MXOiHJcFRWOHFDTURwakk/view) But, take notice, I've only made sure there's no errors during compilation, I haven't tested if it works properly so it's totally up to you. Just import this lib using `org.json` and try to use it.

Comment: @user3820753, I've updated the answer adding compiled lib this Javadoc belongs to, give it a try.

Comment: thanks , i already got it from someone i know . Still thanks.

Comment: @user3820753 You're welcome. Maybe it'll make use for someone else still.